# How to read the child nodes in xml file with xml reader without loading in memory

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file containing tags like

<properties>

<Property><propertyid>12345-CH1612111490</propertyid>

<lastUpdateDate>2015-04-15</lastUpdateDate>

<category>Residential For Rent</category>

</Property>

<Property>
  <propertyid>12345-CH1545111176</propertyid>

<lastUpdateDate>2015-04-15</lastUpdateDate>

<category>Residential For Rent</category>

</Property>

....

....

....n

</properties>

How can we process each  tag one by one with xmlReader or xmltextreader like we do with xmlnodeList by xmldocument.
We don't want to load the full xml in memory so we require it with reader.
 Please help as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. _" Please help as soon as possible."_ >> this is considered bad form, it is considered rude towards all these people giving advice for free, in their own time. If you want good (often fast) answers, make sure to comply with [mcve] (you haven't gotten there yet, please take a moment of your time and have a look). If you are in a rush and/or want someone to do the task for you, this forum, or any forum, may not be the best choice.

Comment: Btw, an example of what you want is in [MSDN with the XmlReader class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and some of its methods.